# PL SQL object type to java

Tags: java, plsql

I would like to pass the `plsql` object type pass to Java. Java will get this object and after modification, I want to pass back the same object to `plsql`.
Main program will be calling from `plsql` to Java and the expecting result return from java is to same object at `plsql`. May I know if there is anyway to ?
Following is the code that I'm trying on it. 
Can plsql object type directly to java method/function as in and out paramter?
I tried to pass the plsql object type with Struct, it can able to compile the program. However, I do not know how can java accept this object and to be converted to java object.

Something like below example. Thank you very much

### PL/SQL object Type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Address AS OBJECT
( street VARCHAR2(30),
   city VARCHAR2(20)
);
```

### PL/SQL Package calling java program

```
create or replace package body TYPE_ADD_TEST is
FUNCTION Test_ADD(in_address IN address
                ) RETURN address IS
LANGUAGE JAVA
NAME 'TestPrg.TestAddress(java.sql.Struct
                   ) return java.sql.Struct';
end TYPE_ADD_TEST;
```

### Java code

```
create or replace and compile java source named testprg as
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class TestPrg{

    public static String TestAddress(Struct TestAddress) {

        Address testAdd = (Address) TestAddress; 
        // Address testAdd = new Address("s","c"); 
        return testAdd.street;
    }

}
```

### Java Object Class

```
create or replace and compile java source named address as
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Address {

    public String street ;
    public String city;  
    public Address() {}
    public Address(String a, String  b) {
        street = "java street";
        city = "java city";
    }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: You want to read this: http://www.stefan-armbruster.com/images/downloads/IT/e10588.pdf - around page 15, he discusses how to create Java classes that can be exchanged with Oracle (extend SQLData), or how to just use a Struct: Structs have a getAttributes() method, that returns an array of attribute values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information . i changed my java code and java object class. getAttributes() method can able to get  the object value of plsql in java method. still struggling to pass back java object type directly as out parameter to plsql.